# what is the substitute for this anonymous inner class?

Tags: java, android, inner-classes, anonymous-class

```
btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{ 
  public void onClick(View v) 
      { 
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
             "Time selected:" +  
             timePicker.getCurrentHour() +  
             ":" + timePicker.getCurrentMinute(), 
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
       } 
});
```

How to convert this to non-anonymous inner class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd simply need to make it an inner class:

```
btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new InnerOnClickListener());

...

private class InnerOnClickListener implements OnClickListener
{
     public void onClick(View v) 
     { 
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Time selected:" +  
                        timePicker.getCurrentHour() +  
                        ":" + timePicker.getCurrentMinute(), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     } 
}
```

Note the use of `getBaseContext()` which will actually be called on the instance of the creating class.

If `timePicker` is a local variable in your method (as opposed to an instance variable in the creating class) you'd need to pass that into a constructor of the inner class.

Comment: The nested class would need to be declared as
    private class InnerOnClickListener extends OnClickListener

Comment: @Brett: Isn't it an interface? Hence implements, not extends. (I corrected my original for that a couple of minutes ago.)

Comment: Thanks Jon. I saw something was a miss. Tried to be helpful.

Comment: private class InnerOnClickListener implements OnClickListener /private class InnerOnClickListener extends OnClickListener

Comment: @skbishi: I don't understand the point your comment was trying to make. Were you asking which you should be using?

Comment: its ok i got it..... jon thx..  (interface are all ways implements) am i right...?

Comment: @Brett: Sorry, that wasn't meant to sound grumpy. I wasn't sure whether you'd seen my correction to make it implement the interface, and were trying to tell me that it should extend it as a class instead, or whether you just hadn't seen my edit. It can get a bit confusing with overlapping edits/comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare an View.OnClickListener interface implementation:

```
btnOpen.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
...
private View.OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Overide
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Time selected:" +
                timePicker.getCurrentHour() +
                ":" + timePicker.getCurrentMinute(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's still an anonymous inner class though, isn't it?

Comment: @basicsharp- my frend your answer is also usefull because now i am able to distinguish between the two